# In python, detect type, then cast to that type

Tags: python

In support of some legacy code, I have to read a text file and parse it for statements like `x=102` and `file=foo.dat` that might be used to overwrite default values.  Note that the second one there is not `file='foo.dat'`; these aren't python statements, but they're close.

Now, I can get the `type` of the default object, so I know that `x` should be an int and `file` should be a str.  So, I need a way to cast the right-hand side to that type.  I'd like to do this programmatically, so that I can call a single, simple default-setting function.  In particular, I'd prefer to not have to loop over all the built-in types.  Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can get the type of the default object"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy:

```
textfromfile = '102'
defaultobject = 101
value = (type(defaultobject))(textfromfile)
```

Now, `value` is an int equal to 102.

Comment: No need for the extra braces: `type(defaultobject)(textfromfile)`

Comment: True.  I just prefer this syntax.

Answer (score 5):

```
# Get the type object from the default value
value_type = type(defaults[fieldname])

# Instantiate an object of that type, using the string from the input
new_value = value_type(override_value)
```